# What is the relation between $sin^{-1}x$ and $cos^{-1}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, inverse-function

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx=\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+C=-\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+C , \text{for} \space |x|<a$$
Can someone why they are equal explain ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not different, since $\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\frac\pi2$, for each $x\in[-1,1]$. So$$\arcsin\left(\frac xa\right)+C=-\arccos\left(\frac xa\right)+\frac\pi2+C.$$

Answer (score 6):

It's because they differ by a constant value of $\frac \pi 2$,  so they are the same up to a constant